# Reversing axes to get Poiseuille profile

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot my velocity profile, similar to this plot (not the arrows, just the shape)

[image]

Here is my function

```
Diam = 2;
Uavg = 200;
SL = 40;
R = Diam/2;
theta[r_] := ArcCos[SL*Diam^2/(8*Uavg*(R^2 - r^2))];
Plot[Piecewise[{{SL/Cos[theta[r]], r >= 0}, {8*R^2*Uavg/Diam^2, 
r = 0}}], {r, 0, 0.99}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want to do is Rotate the graph, there's always the Rotate command:

```
Rotate[Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False], 90 Degree]
```